# Is there any difference usage in external interrupt between GPIO (AHB bus)and those (APB bus)?

Tags: c, arm

I had configured GPIO PR4 to work as external interrupt trigger on raising edge.but the interrupt ISR not trigger.same code worked well with GPIO PC5.My platform is Cortex M3 (TI F28M36x).

GPIO PC5 has same useage with PR4(different interrupt source)worked well.
I had check the external wave in PR4 (high level more than 3.0V).
I found PR4 use AHP bus,but PC5 use APB bus,I wonder is this difference make the different result?
My configure code like this:

```
SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOR);
GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTR_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);
GPIOPinIntClear(GPIO_PORTR_BASE,GPIO_PIN_4);
GPIOIntTypeSet(GPIO_PORTR_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_BOTH_EDGES);   
IntRegister(INT_GPIOR, IntGPIORHandler);
IntEnable(INT_GPIOR);
GPIOPinIntEnable(GPIO_PORTR_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);
```

ISR(IntGPIORHandler) never entered when debug in CCS tools.

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution on TI community.It's not result in AHB problem but driverlib is too old.
https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000/f/171/t/552983?tisearch=e2e-sitesearch&keymatch=GPIO%20port%20R%20interrupt

I use these code instead "IntRegister() and IntEnable()".

```
IntRegister(148, IntGPIORHandler);
HWREG(0xE000E110) = 1 << (132 - 128);
```